# Code for getting Location on a map for provided address

Tags: asp.net

i'm new to this platform,if someone could suggest me with snippets to look into if my app requires to locate an address provided on the google map.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latitide = 50.445516;
    var longitude = 30.452188;
    var addressHiddenField = document.getElementById("<%= AddressCoordinates.ClientID %>");

    if (addressHiddenField.value.length > 0) {
        latitide = parseFloat(addressHiddenField.value.split(";")[0]);
        longitude = parseFloat(addressHiddenField.value.split(";")[1]);
    }

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitide, longitude);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {
    var addressHiddenField = document.getElementById("<%= AddressCoordinates.ClientID %>");
    var address = document.getElementById("<%= AddressTextBox.ClientID %>").value;
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });

            addressHiddenField.value = results[0].geometry.location.lat() + ";" + results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        }
        else {
            addressHiddenField.value = "";
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

Markup:

```
<body onload="initialize()">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 480px;">
</div>
<div>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="AddressTextBox" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="GetAddressCoordinatesButton" OnClientClick="codeAddress()"
        Text="Search Address" />
    <hr />
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="AddressCoordinates" />
</div>
</form>
```